# Have characters show up in text output. Example "\"

Tags: lua

I am trying to write a keyboard in Lua and cannot get "\" to show up in the text box I'm attempting to populate or in the debug via print.  Any suggestions?  I've tried searching for it but the use of \ in the language has made that difficult. Sorry if it's a dumb question in advance, and thanks for the input.  Here's a sample of the code, which is being used to create a keyboard in an QSC audio processor:

```
Controls.right_keys[3].EventHandler = function ()
   if Controls['Shift'].Boolean == false
     then  STRING = '\'; 
           Controls['String'].String = STRING;
   elseif Controls['Shift'].Boolean == true 
     then  STRING = '|'; 
           Controls['String'].String = STRING; 
  end end
```

The code works perfectly with other keyboard pairs such as [ and {

Comment: then STRING = [[ \ ]]; Is it what you want?

Comment: `STRING = string.char(92)` as a last resort :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the slash

```
STRING = '\\'
```